# Correct method to center elements in ionic2

Tags: html, css, ionic2, ionic3

I have placed some text and a button on page. I am currenlty centering it using traditional css methods that i know of. Is this the correct way to center in IONIC 2?

```
<ion-content padding class="login-signup">

  <ion-card>

  <div class="or-label">
   SOME-TEXT
  </div>

  <div class="signup-button">
    <button outline>Signup</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

// corresponding css

```
 .or-label {
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
  }


.signup-button {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

Just like @AndrewGraham-Yooll mentioned in his answer, the `fab-center` attribute was removed a few versions ago, so now the only way to do it would be to use a container with the `text-center` [utility attribute](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/css-utilities/)

```
<ion-content padding class="login-signup">

  <ion-card text-center>
    <div class="or-label">
      SOME-TEXT
    </div>
    <button outline>Signup</button>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

---

<s>You can center the `button` by adding the *Ionic2 attribute* `fab-center` like this:</s>

`<button fab-center outline>Signup</button>`

You can find more information about Ionic2 attributes in [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/button/Button/).

Regarding the other `div`, because it's not an Ionic component (like a button, or label), you should center it by using some traditional `css rules` like you're doing or using a [Utility attribute](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/css-utilities/) like `text-center`.

Please also notice that in your code, there is a missing clossing tag: 
`</ion-card>`

Answer (score 9):

Ionic 2 has some useful [Utility Attributes](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/css-utilities/) that can be added to elements.

In this case adding `text-center` to an element will apply the `text-align: center` property to it, causing its inner content to be centered.

An example using your code would be something like...

```
<ion-card text-center>
    <div class="or-label">
        SOME-TEXT
    </div>
    <button outline>Signup</button>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 8):

@sebferras' answer is no longer correct for release Ionic 2 >2.0.0

You must encase you button in a `div` and apply `text-center`.

```
<div text-center>
   <button ion-button large>
     Click Here
   </button>
</div>
```